# add "xs:Enumeration" XSD using C#

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xsd

How can i add a "xsi:Enumeration" XSD using C#

this is the base file XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema"
     targetNamespace="urn:bookstore-schema"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="TagType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
             <!--here to add new Enum elements -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and i wanna to get this result using c#:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema"
     targetNamespace="urn:bookstore-schema"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="TagType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Actor" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Productor" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Director" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Category" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit an xsd file using System.xml.schema classes.
Detailed example can be found on this support link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318502/en-us

Here is modified code for adding two enumerations into the file and resaving the file.

```
FileStream fs;
XmlSchema schema;
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = 
    new ValidationEventHandler(Class1.ShowCompileErrors);

try
{
    fs = new FileStream("book.xsd", FileMode.Open);
    schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, eventHandler);
    schema.Compile(eventHandler);

    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(schema);
    schemaSet.Compile();
    schema = schemaSet.Schemas().Cast<XmlSchema>().First();

    var simpleTypes =
        schema.SchemaTypes.Values
            .OfType<XmlSchemaSimpleType>()
                .Where(t => t.Content is XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction);

    foreach (var simpleType in simpleTypes)
    {
        XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction = 
        (XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction)simpleType.Content;

        XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet actorEnum = 
            new XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet();

        actorEnum.Value= "Actor";
        restriction.Facets.Add(actorEnum);
        XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet producerEnum = 
            new XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet();

        producerEnum.Value = "Producer";
        restriction.Facets.Add(producerEnum);                       
    }

    fs.Close();
    fs = new FileStream("book.xsd", FileMode.Create);
    schema.Write(fs);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
catch (XmlSchemaException schemaEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(schemaEx.Message);
}
catch (XmlException xmlEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmlEx.Message);
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, i used this example yet, but i don't found how to add <xs:enumeration>

Comment: Ok.. so I have now added the source code through which you can add enumerations. Hope it helps!